# triggering a background task by web client without loosing session

Tags: javascript, php, fat-free-framework

I have a webapp that is supposed to run a resource-intensive task (function) that will take time to complete. I'm triggering this task by calling a url;

```html
http://app.domain.com/process_file/@fileid
```

However, as expected, the web client waits for the task (function) to complete. This is likely to cause time outs.

Please suggest ways i can trigger the task and let the user continue navigating the webapp.

I have tried the following so far;

```
1. JQuery/ajax
2. Redirecting to a _blank page
```

NB: I have no access to the crontab or Scheduler. I'm using PHP, JavaScript & fat-free framework

Comment: Can you show us what you already have

Comment: I would propose to use a real background worker solution instead of this approach. Your approach will occupy one worker per long-running request. The website will be unusable as soon as all workers are occupied with a long running task, e.g. when requesting `process_file/@fileid` multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [abort](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/base#abort) function:

```
function (Base $f3) {
  // process request and send response to client (could be a redirect status)
  $f3->abort(); // disconnect the client
  // perform consuming task here
}
```

This is basically the solution suggested by Pavel Třupek, wrapped in a method for convenience.

Comment: Thanks @xfra35. This worked for me. The browser opens a new tab for the link (http://app.domain.com/process_file/@fileid) and immediately abort. However the task gets called on the back-end as expected. But if it is not too much trouble, can you suggest if it possible to prevent the new tab (http://app.domain.com/process_file/@fileid) from opening or alternatively open&shut it at the point i call $f3->abort()

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. If you don't want the link to open a new tab, then remove the `target="_blank"` attribute. But if you don't want the link to open anything at all, then just send the request in AJAX (and maybe you don't need the `abort()` method then).

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the page via curl like:

```
$curl = curl_init();                
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_exec($curl);   
curl_close($curl);
```

which calls url and immediately timeouts it.

And then in your expensive script:

```
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
header("Content-Length: 1");
ignore_user_abort(true);
//your code
```